# Call to function 'CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am converting my project to ARC and Xcode thinks there is a memory leak here, does anyone see anything wrong with this?  I didn't write this code so I am not familiar with C calls.

```
- (NSString*) URLEscaped
{

    NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                NULL,
                                (CFStringRef)self,
                                NULL,
                                (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    return encodedString;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html):

> There are many ways in which you can get a reference to an object
> using Core Foundation. In line with the Core Foundation ownership
> policy, you need to know whether or not you own an object returned by
> a function so that you know what action to take with respect to memory
> management. Core Foundation has established a naming convention for
> its functions that allows you to determine whether or not you own an
> object returned by a function. In brief, if a function name contains
> the word "Create" or "Copy", you own the object. If a function name
> contains the word "Get", you do not own the object.

Yes, you're leaking a `CFString` there.

Comment: So I am okay to use autorelease here then?

Comment: Yes, `autorelease` on returned object should be fine.

Comment: Except that you can't use `-autorelease` in ARC and ARC won't like that cast. You should declare `encodedString` as a `CFStringRef` instead of an `NSString*` and then do `return CFBridgingRelease(encodedString);`. The bridging release balances the Core Foundation "Create" while handing ownership of the object over to ARC.

Comment: Okay thanks, however its a third party library so I am not going to convert any third party code to arc.

Answer (score 4):

Under ARC you can use __bridge_transfer to transfer memory management of the returned string to ARC:

```
NSString *encodedString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                            NULL,
                            (CFStringRef)self,
                            NULL,
                            (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```